# How to parse string to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I have a string like below

```
var str = "{u'MALWARE TROJAN_HORSE': 16, u'MALWARE DUQU': 0, u'MALWARE STUXNET': 8, u'MALWARE STALLING_MANUFACTURING_PLANTS': 1, u'MALWARE VIRUS': 0, u'MALWARE WORM': 0, u'MALWARE NUCLEAR_POWER_PLANTS': 8}"
```

I need to pass it to google visualization api chart as data object in the form as show below:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['query', 'count'],
        ['Virus', 8175000],
        ['Malware', 3792000],
        ['Struxnet', 1526000]
      ]);
```

Actually i want convert that **str** object to the JSON format above and add a first array item `['query', 'count']` also to the parsed string

How to do this

Comment: @Barmar not even true, dude

Comment: You would need to determine the format that `str`'s value is in and find an appropriate parser. (It appears to be possibly a Python dictionary literal.) Or, use a different format (such as JSON) for the initial value.

Comment: As an aside: The 2nd snippet, with `google.visualization`, doesn't depict JSON. That would be a [JavaScript Array Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (or literal). JSON's array syntax was based on JavaScript's, which is why they're similar, but the two still exist separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string your are working with is not valid JSON. You should properly stringify it in your backend before passing it to the client.

A quick and dirty solution with your current input would be to normalize your string and then use `JSON.parse`:

```
var cleanedString = s.replace(/u/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"');
var data = JSON.parse(cleanedString);

// now that we have an actual object, construct the desired array from it
var mappedData = ['query', 'count'].concat(Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
  return [key, data[key]];
}));
```